# (Django) Reverse dynamic urls with multiple arguments using Django Views

Tags: django, url, dynamic

I am trying to pass two arguments to make a dynamic URL for each post of a blog app I'm working on. I get it to work if I pass the id, but don't know what's the syntax when using +1 arguments (nor if I'm doing things right).

I want to make urls be `'post/<int:pk>/<slug:slug>/'` but can only make it work with the id: `'post/<int:pk>/`

Here's how I have it now:

URLS.PY

```py
    urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('post/<int:pk>/<slug:slug>/', PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post-detail'),
    path('post/new/', PostCreateView.as_view(), name='post-create'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/<slug:slug>/update/', PostUpdateView.as_view(), name='post-update'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/<slug:slug>/delete/', PostDeleteView.as_view(), name='post-delete'),
    ...
    ]
```

VIEWS.PY

```py
   class PostDetailView(DetailView):
        model = Post
```

I am calling this in the template:

```py
   <ul class="secondary-menu menu-list">
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="{% url 'post-update' object.slug %}">Edit Post</a></li>
    <li class="red-button"><a href="{% url 'post-delete' object.slug %}">Delete</a></li>
    </ul>
```

And have this function to retrieve the path to any specific instance in MODELS.py

```py
   def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk, 'slug':slug})
```

I get the following error during template rendering

```
Reverse for 'post-detail' with arguments '(1,)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['post/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/(?P<slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/$']
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk, 'slug':self.slug})
```

you missed the `self` in `slug`, else you need to pass `slug` as a `parameter` to the `function` if `self` is not needed.

Comment: I made the change, but still get the same error. May it be something about how I'm passing the url in the template? Because when I use only the id and call the url as `<a href="{% url 'post-update' object.id %}">Edit Post</a>` it works. But when I add the second argument (slug), it breaks `<a href="{% url 'post-update' object.id object.slug %}">Edit Post</a>`

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `slug` as `self.slug` and also if slug is empty or null your reverse url will not work.

```
get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk, 'slug':self.slug})
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the error.

The settings for the files URLS.PY, VIEWS.PY were ok.

As both @Exprator and @Mohammed Aadil mentioned, I was missing the `self` in `slug` in the MODELS.PY file.

But I kept having the same error because I didn't update the `urls` from all the `html` templates. By the way, if you're not sure about the syntax on passing multiple arguments to a `url`, here's how it worked for me: `{% url 'post-detail' post.id post.slug %}`