# How to write {% url ' ' %} for 2 and more slug arguments?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-urls

I try to generate url for "go to next url" but when i use `{% url tuman_url 'iib:mahalla' i.slug %}` i get error:

> Reverse for 'mahalla' with arguments '(<Tuman: Sharof Rashidov Tumani>, 'ulugbek')' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P<tuman_slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/mahalla/(?P<mahalla_slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\Z']

urls.py

```
path('statistika/<slug:tuman_slug>/', show_one_stata, name='tuman_stata'),
path('<slug:tuman_slug>/mahalla/<slug:mahalla_slug>', show_one_mahalla, name='mahalla'),
```

views.py

```
def show_one_stata (request,tuman_slug:str):
    tuman_url = get_object_or_404(Tuman, slug=tuman_slug)
    tuman = Tuman.objects.all()
    citizen = Citizen.objects.all()
    category = Category.objects.all()
    mahalla = Mahalla.objects.

    context = {
        'citizen' : citizen,
        'category' : category,
        'mahalla' : mahalla,
        'tuman' : tuman,
        'tuman_url' : tuman_url,

    return render(request, 'main/one_stata.html',context)


def show_one_mahalla(request, mahalla_slug:str,tuman_slug:str) :
    citizen = Citizen.objects.all()
    nizo = Category.objects.all()
    mahalla_for = get_object_or_404(Mahalla, slug=mahalla_slug)
    tuman_url = get_object_or_404(Tuman, slug=mahalla_slug)


    context = {
        'citizen':citizen,
        'nizo':nizo,
        'mahalla_for':mahalla_for,
        'tuman_url':tuman_url,

        }
    return render(request, 'main/one_mahalla.html',context)
```

my html

```
    {% for i in mahalla %}
    {% if i.tum == tuman_url %}
    <tr>
        <td style="font-weight: bold;"><a href="{% url tuman_url 'iib:mahalla' i.slug %}" style="text-decoration:none; color:black;">{{ i.name }}</a></td>
   <tr>
    {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
```

models.py

```
class Tuman(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, db_index=True, verbose_name="Tuman")
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, unique=True, db_index=True, verbose_name="URL")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('iib:tuman', kwargs={'tuman_slug': self.pk})

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Tumanlar'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Tumanlar'

class Mahalla(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, db_index=True, verbose_name="Mahallaning nomi")
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, unique=True, db_index=True, verbose_name="URL")
    tum = models.ForeignKey('Tuman',on_delete=models.PROTECT,null=True,blank=True, verbose_name= "Tuman")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('iib:mahalla', kwargs={'mahalla_slug': self.pk})

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Mahalla'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Mahallalar'
```

Comment: Generating url with multiple arguments is as [trivial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58387545/django-reverse-dynamic-urls-with-multiple-arguments-using-django-views) as with single argument. In templates you can use [named](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/templates/builtins/#url)  approach or omit argument names. But your code is riddled with errors, thus no chance to fix your project with a single tip about url reversion. Please read the docs about url reversion and thoroughly review your current code.

Comment: `reverse('iib:mahalla', kwargs={'mahalla_slug': self.pk})` but `mahalla` url pattern requires two arguments. where is the second? why passing `self.pk` instead of `slug`? `{% url tuman_url 'iib:mahalla' i.slug %}` - url pattern name must be the first argument of `url` template tag. `tuman_url = get_object_or_404(Tuman, slug=mahalla_slug)` why do you call it `url`? It's the whole object instance. Why `Tuman` filtered by `mahalla_slug` not by `tuman_slug`?